# The Neviim - Caves, solitude, hitbodedut - how much were they separate from the masses?

Tags: navi-prophets

Can you assist me in understanding if the neviim did in fact go into their caves specifically for hitbodedut, to not be overwhelmed by the throngs of people needing their visions, or just to collect themselves and be at one with Hashem.